# Customize Transaction/Order details - PayPal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I just wanna ask, if there's any provision to customize transaction/order details available in Merchant or Buyer logins. Please refer below screen shots.
[image: Order Summary Page]

I'm aware of the way to change relevant details on Order Summary page and have already done that. This can be witnessed in above image (encircled areas). But these details do not reflect on Transaction/Order details page, as in image below.

[image: Transaction/Order details]

This issue is shared among Merchant & Buyer logins.